# How to creation of multiple json arrays at a go?

Tags: arrays, json

I need to create multiple Json arrays at a single instance. I have 38 rows. For 38 rows first I need to create 38 empty JSON arrays. Then in each JSON array i need to add first column of row as first object in all the arrays. Second column as 2nd object etc. Is there a way to specify the position to add the objects in each array?

```
[
 [
  {
   "fileName": "123"
  },
  {
    "id": "100"
  },
  {
    "product": ""
  }
],
[
  {
    "fileName": "123"
  },
  {
    "id": "100"
  },
  {
    "product": ""
  }
 ]...38
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package emp;

import javax.lang.model.element.PackageElement;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Temp 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        jsonArray.put(createJsonArray("name 1", "id 1", "product 1"));
        jsonArray.put(createJsonArray("name 2", "id 2", "product 2"));
        jsonArray.put(createJsonArray("name 3", "id 3", "product 3"));

        System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());
    }

    public static JSONArray createJsonArray(String name, String id, String product) throws JSONException
    {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("fileName", "123");
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
        jsonObject.put("id", "123");
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
        jsonObject.put("product", "product");
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
        return jsonArray;
    }
}
```